# WEBAPI stops response for request

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, iis-7.5

I wrote a simple testing WEB API to convert docx files to pdf (by using 3rd party library). Code as below:

```
    [Route("PDFConvert/Convert")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult ConvertFile(string name)
    {
        var content = Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
        try
        {
            if (content != null)
            {
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    content.CopyTo(ms);

                    Converter.Convert(ms.ToArray(), @".docx", @"c:\pdftest\" + name + @".pdf");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return Content(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "No source file supplied.");                    
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError(new Exception(ex.Message));
        }

        return Ok("File " + name + ".docx has been converted.");
    }
```

This code works for single call.

Then I wrote some testing code in a console programe to simulate there are a lot of requests hit the api, codes below:

```
        for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++)
        {

            var filestream = File.OpenRead(@"c:\pdftest\" + i.ToString() + @".docx");
            test(filestream, i.ToString());
        }

    static void test(FileStream fs, string id)
    {
        var content = new StreamContent(fs);
        var client = new HttpClient();

        //post to web api
        var response = client.PostAsync("http://localhost/WebAPI.PDFConvertion/PDFConvert/Convert?name=" + id, content);


        Console.WriteLine("File Name: " + id + ".pdf");
        client.Dispose();
    }
```

This WEB API was hosted in IIS 7.5 with all default settings.

Now comes the issue: after converting some files (all the origin docx file are the same, just different file name), the whole process stops.

In my test, if the origin files size are big (>1M), it always stops after converting 37 files, and if the origin files size are small (like 20KB), it always stops after 69.

If I don't use the API and move the converting code to console to test, all good, all 100 files are converted one by one.

In the real scenario there are thousands of docx files need to be converted and we're planning to make a request to the API per file, that means thousands request in a short period.

So, could you guys give a clue how to solve this issue? Do I need to modify some settings of the IIS?

Please let me know if you have any questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually found the solution myself. It is all about the HttpClient which has a default timeout value of 100 seconds.

So when there are a lot of concurrent requests hit the API, some of them will execute immediately, some of them have to wait for the free resources. If those requests wait for too long, like longer than the httpclient timeout time, error occurs.

So increased the timeout value to a value that needed and all works perfect now.

Example:

```
var client = new HttpClient();  
 client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
```